# When I open Eclipse 3.7.2 I get this error "Initializing error tooling" Android

Tags: java, android, initializing, tooling

So I am using Eclipse 3.7.2 to program android appications but now that I open it up I get the error "Initializing error tooling" It didn't used to do it before so I don't know what happened. All I can remember is that recently I updated some SDK stuff and Eclipse itself to the newest version so that may be causing the problem. So if you know what this is, or if I should worry about it please help me thank you.

An screen capture image of my problem http://i50.tinypic.com/106n9z9.png

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates a corrupt workspace. Try loading Eclipse with a fresh workspace, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried making a new one. And it said the same thing. I then went into my workspace folder deleted some unused projects and went in eclipse and deleted them in there. And closed eclipse and opened it back up and no error message. (SO THATS GOOD) But I'm still getting this on my console tab (Image of my problem ---> http://i46.tinypic.com/2jbrvx4.png   and this one go together http://i47.tinypic.com/1hz1v6.png) Long image sorry.

Comment: Never mind, I reinstalled the 2.3.3 SDK and it fixed it. Thank you though.